# Apply dplyr function which contains "group_by" to multiple columns

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse, apply

Data:

```
structure(list(Reversal_MSignal = c(0, 0, 0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Reversal_MSignal_time = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have a column called Reversal_MSignal and I would like to create a new column called Reversal_MSignal_time which is a number sequence that restarts from 1 when `Reversal_MSignal != 0`.

The following code creates the wanted column. However, the problem is that I need to create this type of column for a multiple columns

```
data %>% group_by(gr = cumsum(Reversal_MSignal != 0)) %>% 
  mutate(Reversal_MSignal = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  select(-gr)
}
```

I was thinking about creating a function and then applying it through "apply" or through `mutate(across(everything(), Timeframe))`.

```
Timeframe <- function(Column){
group_by(gr = cumsum(Column != 0)) %>% 
  mutate(Column = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  select(-gr) %>% 
  rename(Reversal_MSignal_time = Reversal_MSignal)
}

df %>% lapply(., Timeframe)
```

however, I get this error with `lapply` and with `mutate` it doesn't behave as wanted

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

I'm also open to faster solutions however I would prefer those using dplyr package as it is easier for me to understand what is going on

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem was that the `group_by` inside your function was not being passed the data frame as the first argument.  You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(Reversal_MSignal = c(0, 0, 0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                       Reversal_MSignal_time = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Timeframe <- function(data, Column){
    data %>% 
        group_by(gr = cumsum(.data[[Column]] != 0)) %>% 
        mutate("{{Column}}.time" := row_number()) %>% 
        ungroup() %>% 
        select(-gr) %>% 
        rename_with(~str_remove_all(., "\\\""))
}

Timeframe(data, "Reversal_MSignal")
Timeframe(data, "Reversal_MSignal_time")

reduce(names(data), Timeframe, .init = data)
```

The `reduce` statement will loop through all of the columns of `data` and apply the `Timeframe` function, and then use the output as the next input.

Comment: The problem still persists with the `reduce` function. It creates columns which are just a sequence from 1 to 10

Comment: Okay, I fixed it.  There was a problem with non-standard evaluation because `reduce` was passing strings from the `names` output.  Also, I don't know how to get the `mutate` to avoid putting the extra quotation marks in the new column name, so I added a `rename_with` inside the `Timeframe` function.